# What is the purpose of the -Hu argument for sudo?

Tags: apache-2.2, sudo

I've seen several sudo commands that begin as so:

```
sudo -Hu apache
```

What is the purpose of the -Hu argument, and how does it pertain to the `apache` command that follows?

Comment: (Nearly) all commands and programs come with an online manual, accessed with the [`man`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html) command, that document usage instructions and the available command line options. So please read the fine manual [`man sudo`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.18/sudo.man.html).

Answer (score 3):

sets $HOME to the apache user's home directory, and executes whatever would follow *sudo -Hu apache* as the apache user.

Ex: *sudo -Hu apache ls ~* would execute *ls ~* as the apache user with $HOME set to the apache user's home, listing *apache*'s home directory contents